# What is a cost effective serverless pattern for SQS FIFO and Lambda to delay messages by Message Group Id?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sqs

I want to be able to delay messages coming through an SQS FIFO queue by a defined period of time. This delay needs to be at the Message Group ID level.
Please provide advice on your solution, or on my solutions.

### Requirements

Sequential message processing

Message processing no-faster-than 2 minutes per message per message group ID.

### Example

Messages 1, 2, 3 come in to a FIFO queue, for Message Group ID A, all 1 second after each other.

Let's say it's 10am.

- Message 1 can be processed immediately (presuming no previous messages for that group id have come in, or been processed recently)
- Message 2, should not process before 10:02am
- Message 3, should not process until 2 minutes after message 2 has processed (10:04am in this example)

### Current thought process

I have 2 solutions in my head

#### Solution 1:

- SQS FIFO triggers a lambda
- Create a dynamoDB to handle processing time
- On reciept of the message by a lambda, it checks the dyanmoDB for last message process time for that group id
- If less than 2 minutes ago > fail the lambda

  - A message visibility timeout on the queue of 2 minutes should allow this to re-appear after the 2 minute window has passed

#### Solution 2:

- Trigger a lambda that calls a step function on message receive
- Incorporate a wait on the step function at the end of the processing before deleting the message

### Things I've ruled out:

Message delay won't solve the problem. If messages come in 1 second after each other, and processing time is brief (1 second on average), will just result in the messages being processed rapidly, just n seconds later than their arrival.

Setting a wait in the lambda that processes them
This could run up costs on the lambda, even if the lambda was set to it's lowest memory allocation

Comment: For the second solution you don't need a lambda to execute Step Functions. Step Functions can be triggered directly via an EventBridge Pipe: https://serverlessland.com/patterns/eventbridge-pipes-sqs-to-stepfunctions-cdk-python

Comment: Thank you! Interested to try this out too, thanks for the link!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common ask... The ability to **throttle the processing of messages**, typically due to limitations imposed by an external system.

Unfortunately, **native SQS functionality can't address this requirement**. I would recommend against intentionally triggering Lambda failure as a form of 're-queuing' -- it could cause problems when there is a backlog of messages. Don't abuse a system designed for one purpose to try and make it fit another purpose.

Instead, **I'd recommend implementing your own logic** by putting the 'queue' in a database, then having an 'orchestrator' that determines when a message is able to be processed and invokes the Lambda function directly. The Lambda function would either need to update the database to say that it has finished processing the message, or it could return information to the orchestrator that then updates the database.

The **orchestrator** would either need to be 'continuously running code' (eg on EC2 or ECS) or it could be an AWS Lambda function triggered every minute or so.

Comment: Thanks John, I was wondering along these lines but wasn't able to articulate it.
Are you suggesting something along the lines of:::

*Event Storage*:::
SQS (no need for FIFO if messages are timestamped at creation) -> DynamoDB to persist the message

*Event Processing*:::
ECS function in my language of choice with (*loosely) the logic of:::
Select message_body from DynamoDB
where unprocessed = true
group_by customer
order by received_date asc

Comment: Yes. You'll also need a way to track the "last sent time" so it waits before sending another message for that customer. You could delete the record from DynamoDB when processed and a later message has been sent. Or, you could put the 'smarts' in the process that stores the message in the database -- it could 'schedule' the time when the message should be sent, so that the orchestrator simply asks the database for what messages to send during the current minute.

Comment: I really appreciate the thoroughness of your response John!